# How can I optmize this Python code?

Tags: python

I'm making a code that receive a list of phone numbers and then checks if one or more of the numbers is a prefix of other numbers in the list. I want to optimize to the maximum so that it can run as fast as possible. Here's the code:

```
cases = []

t = int(input())

for i in range(0, t):
    n = int(input())
    case = []
    for j in range(0, n):
        case.append(str(input()))
    cases.append(sorted(case))

print(cases)

for c in cases:
    answer = 'YES'
    for k in range(0, len(c)):
        if answer == 'YES':
            for l in range(0, len(c)):
                if c[k] != c[l]:            
                    if c[k] == c[l][0:len(c[k])]:
                        answer = 'NO'
                        break
        else:
            break
    print(answer)
```

**Edit:** Using the answer proposed by @Gelineau, the code run in 0.82s, being that before it went from >3s to reach the solution. With that now the solution looks like this:

```
cases = []

t = int(input())

for i in range(0, t):
    n = int(input())
    case = []
    for j in range(0, n):
        case.append(str(input()))
    cases.append(case)

for case in cases:
    answer = 'YES'
    case.sort()    
    for case_k, case_next in zip(case, case[1:]):
        if case_k == case_next[:len(case_k)]:
            answer = 'NO'
            break
    print(answer)
```

Comment: `resposta` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks  for notifying man, I just forgot to rename it when parsing into the editor.

Comment: Rewrite it in C.

Comment: Or run it in Cython or Pypy - with those it is possible to get C-like speeds with regular Python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ktzr's answer requires n*n comparisons, with n = len(case).
You could sort case first (n * log(n) operations), and then you need only compare one case_k with the next one in the list (n operations).

```
case.sort()
for case_k, case_next in zip(case, case[1:]):
    if case_k == case_next[:len(case_k)]:
        answer = 'NO'
        break
```

EDITED:

You can also use a generator expression:

```
case.sort()
answer = all(case_k != case_next[:len(case_k)] for case_k, case_next in zip(case, case[1:]))
```

(answer will be True or False). It will not be faster, but it is clearer IMHO

Comment: Great solution, I wish I had thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be **very** fast then python is probibly not the right choice. But you can make some small changes like instead of

```
for i in range(len(c): 
    use c[i] ...
```

you can use

```
for i in range(len(c): 
    use i ...
```

also `answer == 'YES'` will always be true because you brake when you make it False. I ended up reducing your code to this:

```
for case in cases:
    answer = 'YES'
    for case_k, case_l in product(case,case):
        if case_k != case_l and case_k == case_l[:len(case_k)]:
            answer = 'NO'
            break
    print(answer)
```

You can't really speed up IO, you *can* change it to a list gen, but you don't really gain anything and readability suffers a lot:

```
cases = [sorted([str(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]) for _ in range(int(input()))]
```

**Edit:** Based on the comment left by @Gelineau I thought I'd give it another go.

But it still grows in O(n^2) time.

```
cases = ["".join([input() for _ in range(int(input()))]) for _ in range(int(input()))]
#cases = ['123', '4321', '12345']

for i,case_a in enumerate(cases):
    for case_b in cases[i+1:]:
        if case_b.startswith(case_a):
            print(case_a, "is a prefix")
            break
    else:
        print(case_a, "is not a prefix")
```

Comment: Still not enough... I'm wondering if this is the simplest way to make this comparison but I can not think of another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, since the list sorted, you may compare the adjacent records directly with one loop

```
['2345','1234','123','4567','12345','21234'] => ['123', '1234', '12345', '21234', '2345', '4567']
```

If the previous record length is less than current one and current first X numbers equal to previous. Then find and break.

Thanks